Can't join PS5 friend in TM 2020 due to crossplay settings
I (a PC player) am trying to play crossplay with a friend that plays on PS5 in Trackmania 2020.
I'm trying to play with them in the ranked mode. I click invite players from Ubisoft Connect and then select the blue Invite button next to my friend (we are friends in Ubisoft Connect).
When I click the invite button, it says the game invite was sent, but underneath my friend's handle, it says Cannot be invited due to crossplay settings. Crossplay is on for both of us. My friend also can't see the invite I sent.
How do I fix this?

This is probably a problem on your friend's console, tell them to check their privacy settings on PS5. Is the same happening when your friend invites you?

@pinckerman They checked their privacy settings and changed some things around. They don't remember what exactly they changed, but if you want to post that as a general answer, I'll accept it.

I had a similar problem when playing with my friends, and it appeared to be some restrictions on PS5 privacy settings.
Tell your friend to check their settings, there's an option related to invitations or something like that. That should fix the issue.
